# Result of free command in openShift pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

If I execute "free" command in the pod (openshift/kubernetes), what output I will get.

Will I get the memory utilisation of pod or memory utilisation of node where pod exist.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the node. Some things like that don't relate to the pod but fall back to the node. Another example is uptime. That is also for the node.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Graham Dumpleton